# Not able to parse a json post from javascript in Python

Tags: javascript, python

This is the string I'm receiving from the get request:

```
{'company_code': u'ha', 'from-date': u'', 'to-date': u'', 'ledger_type': u'CLNT', 'cost_center': u'ALL', 'margin': u'wtmg'}
```

Now, I'm completely confused what to do with this. I want to make str['company_code'] give me "ha" as output.

But even if I do json.dumps() or loads() on it, I'm just not able to access it.

Any help?

Edit:
After sending a JSON string from the javascript client, and taking a json.dumps, I get this:

```
{"company_code": "ha", "from-date": "", "to-date": "", "ledger_type": "CLNT", "cost_center": "ALL", "margin": "wtmg"}
```

which is a string. I'm not sure how to go forward from here.

Comment: Can you please precise in your question in which direction the data is going? I guess you have a javascript client and python server. You sent data in JSON format from python to javascript but you did not use `json.dumps` and that's why python is issuing it's unicode special `u""` formatting. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given string is not a valid JSON. It seems like a result of `repr`.

```
>>> print(repr({'company_code': u'ha'}))
{'company_code': u'ha'}
```

JSON string should be wrapped in double qutoe ('"').

```
>>> print(json.dumps({'company_code': u'ha'}))
{"company_code": "ha"}
```

---

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('"a"')
u'a'
>>> json.loads("'a'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

**EDIT** according to the question edit.

Use [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) to decode the json string; then access the value using [`dict[key]`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mapping-types-dict) syntax.

```
>>> encoded = '{"company_code": "ha", "from-date": "", "to-date": "", "ledger_type": "CLNT", "cost_center": "ALL", "margin": "wtmg"}'
>>> decoded = json.loads(encoded)
>>> decoded['company_code']
u'ha'
```

Comment: Anyway I could parse it then?

Comment: @Hick, You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in Python: `decoded = ast.literal_eval(the_given_string)`. It will works as long as it only contains `str`, `unicode`, `int`, `float`, ...

Comment: Or maybe I could try to send json from the javascript client.

Comment: @Hick, Yes, that is better than using `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @Hick, But, it seems like the string is originated from Python. (Do you see `u` prefix in the string literal?). You should dump json in Python part.

Comment: I edited my question. I did send a JSON from my client but still facing issues.

Comment: Booyah! Figured it out myself. But shall accept your answer. Thanks for the response, though. Much appreciate it.